# Input filed is not clickable in react while using value attribute

Tags: reactjs

This is the very beginning of my react learning. I am facing some issue about input field. If I use value field in form then this input filed become unchangeable. Like I can't write anything on that filed. But while I remove value filed it work fine. 
Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class Registration extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(e){

    this.setState = ({
        name: e.target.value
    });
}
render(){
    return(
            <div className="registration">
                <form name="registration" id="registration" >
                <div className="userName">
                    <label> Name : </label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.name}/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                    <label> Email : </label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" />
                    <br/>
                    <label> Password : </label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                    <br/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
}
}
```

On the name input field I am using value attribute. This is making this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you accidentally wrote

```
this.setState = ({
    name: e.target.value
});
```

Instead of

```
this.setState({
    name: e.target.value
});
```

The `=` is incorrect, as you're trying to call a method and not declare a variable with a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I was trying over 2 hours for this. Thank you soo much

Comment: @Fokrule You may accept the answer to express thank you.

Comment: Before 6 minute of posted question I can't accept. While 6 minute is complete then I will be able to accept. And Must I will accept as other people could get proper answer if face same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your `this.setState` is set wrong.

```js
class Registration extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="registration">
        <form name="registration" id="registration">
          <div className="userName">
            <label> Name : </label>
            <input
              name="name"
              type="text"
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
              value={this.state.name}
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <label> Email : </label>
          <input name="email" type="email" />
          <br />
          <label> Password : </label>
          <input name="password" type="password" />
          <br />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Registration />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```